# TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/ - But yes, it's in there

Tags: python, django

Project structure:

```
sitename
    db.sqlite3
    home
        __init.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        static
            home.html
            services.html
            contact.html
        views.py
    manage.py
    mysite
        __init.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

This is in my settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
```

This is in my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

from home.models import Home, Services, Contact

import mysite.urls


def Admin(request):
    pass

def Home(request):
    return render_to_response(
        template_name = 'home.html',
        )

def Services(request):
    pass
```

I've tried putting slashes in around home.html, tried changing a few things in settings.py. So far no good. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add `home` part of the path.  And add comma `,` to make the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` a tuple:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home', 'static'), )
```

But anyway you shouldn't do it this way.  Templates should be in the `templates` directory.  Rename `home/static` to `home/templates` and all will work fine even without `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting.

Also don't use `render_to_response` shortcut. Replace this call with [render()](http://ps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

Comment: Which is better? I had TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home', 'static'), ) before, but TEMPLATE_DIRS = [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home', 'static'))] also works.

Comment: This is why it is a good habit to write a comma `,` after the every values in the tuple :-)